# weird namespace typing with generic classes C#

Tags: c#, generics, namespaces

I have a C# program and the following (novice I suppose) problem:

```
namespace ObjectReference
{
    public class A<TypeC>
    {
        public B b;

        public void MethodA()
        {
            b = new B(this);
        }
    }
}
```

and in a different file in the same project:

```
namespace ObjectReference    
{    
    public class B    
    {   
        public A<TypeC> a;

        public B(A<TypeC> myObjA)    
        {    
            a = myObjA;   
        }
    }    
}
```

In the file where class A is defined I get this error on line "`b = new B(this);`": `"Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ObjectReference.A<TypeC>' to 'ObjectReference.A<ObjectReference.TypeC>'"`.

I've tried everything, I can't solve this and I don't understand why it shows up, all the classes are defined inside the same namespace ObjectReference (that is classes A, B and TypeC). It's like in class A it considers the type of the class to be `ObjectReference.A<TypeC>`, whereas in class B it considers the type to be `ObjectReference.A<ObjectReference.TypeC>`.

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: Is everything in the same assembly?

Comment: Show the declaration of `TypeC`. Du you have any `using` statements in your files? Seems like there are two definitions of `TypeC`.

Answer (score 2):

What you're writing is the equivalent of this:

```
public class A<T>
{
    public B b;

    public void MethodA()
    {
        b = new B(this);
    }
}

public class B    
{   
    public A<TypeC> a;

    public B(A<TypeC> myObjA)    
    {    
        a = myObjA;   
    }
}
```

Notice that I've written class A as `A<T>` rather than `A<TypeC>`. Even though you've put a valid type name it's a legal C# generic type so within the definition of the class A `TypeC` isn't the same as the class `TypeC`. Hence the error message you're getting.

To make this work you need to do something like this:

```
public class A<T>
{
    public B<T> b;

    public void MethodA()
    {
        b = new B<T>(this);
    }
}

public class B<T> 
{   
    public A<T> a;

    public B(A<T> myObjA)    
    {    
        a = myObjA;   
    }
}
```

Then you can call the code like so:

```
var a = new A<TypeC>();
a.MethodA();
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to tell class B to have a constructor accepting an instance of type A without any type specification. You can either update class B accepting a type parameter just like class A:

```
public class B<T>
{
    ...
}
```

or you can make the constructor of Class b more concrete specifying the type parameter for him like:

```
public B(A<string> myObjA)
{
    a = myObjA;
}
```

For more information about this type parameter, i suggest you look up some information about generics. There are tons of books and articles out there!

**edit**

I see you updated the code. This still wont be sufficient unless TypeC is an actual type which you havent given us. This however would be a very difficult to understand naming scenario. Basically in class A you define a generic type parameter that can be specified under the name TypeC and in class B you assume a type with this name exists. I still recommend you doing some reading on generics.

Comment: Here is TypeC, defined, like I said, in the same project, same namespace, in a different file: 

namespace ObjectReference
{
    public class TypeC
    {
        public string stringC;
        public TypeC()
        {
            stringC = "stringC";
        }
    }
}

So I do specify the type parameter in the constructor in class B.

The snippet I gave here is a simplified version of my actual code, but this is the problem I need to handle. I will do extensive reading on generics, however I hoped someone had an idea on how to solve this.
Thanks

Comment: @laail : Please add this info to your question and format it properly.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass a generic implementation of A into a constructor of B that takes a non-generic implentation of A. This unfortunatly does not work and will require some rewriting of the class B.

What would work however would be something like:

```
namespace ObjectReference
{
    public class B<TypeC>
    {
        public A<TypeC> a;

        public B(A<TypeC> myObjA) 
        {
            a = myObjA;
        }
    }
 }
```

and then call it as:

```
b = new B<TypeC>(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

`A<TypeC>` is a so called open generic type which you cannot pass as method argument.

To fix this you need to make `B` generic too. Using `A<TypeC>` within `B<TypeC>` now makes `A<TypeC>` a constructed open generic type. This just means that the generic type parameter of B is "derived" to `A<TypeC>`.

You might want to have a look at the [MSDN page about generic classes in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz6zd40f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

```
namespace ObjectReference    
{    
    public class B<TypeC>    
    {   
        public A<TypeC> a;

        public B(A<TypeC> myObjA)    
        {    
            a = myObjA;   
        }
    }    
}
```